# Extraer path actual a variable en javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variables, rutas

estoy diseñando mi árbol genealógico y quiero presentar la ficha de cada persona en formato web, aunque realmente esto lo voy a hacer funcionar en local, no quiero subir todo esto a ningún servidor web. He creado una carpeta por cada individuo, pero ya llevo más de 500 (y creciendo) y como la estructura de las fichas es la misma, me gustaría automatizar determinadas cosas. He nombrado las carpetas con el formato "[id] - [nombre y apellidos]", siendo "[id]" un número de 5 cifras, y quería hacer un fichero base index.html (esto sería la ficha de cada uno) en el que cada vez que deba aparecer el nombre de la persona, lo extraiga de la propia carpeta. ¿Sabéis si puedo hacer esto en javascript? la idea sería almacenar en una variable la ruta donde se encuentra el fichero index.html y mostrar esa variable en pantalla. He hecho varias búsquedas, pero no encuentro nada que me funcione. Gracias!

Comment: De poder se puede -¿Cómo? va a depender de como lo estas haciendo. Entonces debes mostrar tu implementación, para que a partir de ella podamos ayudarte, es decir un [MRE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo y depende de como sea tú código (en tu caso local), te pongo ejemplos genéricos por si te pueden valer

- Para sacar el dato de una URL ej: `http:/web/base/id-nombre-apellidos/` usa

```
   const location = window.location.href;
   const directoryPath = location.substring(0, location.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

- Para sacar la ruta local sin el dominio (web) ej: `/base/id-nombre-apellidos/` usa

```
   const location = window.location.pathname;
   const directoryPath = location.substring(0, location.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

- Si solo quieres el nombre del directorio donde se ejecuta el script ej: `id-nombre-apellidos` usa

```
    const location = window.location.pathname;
    const path = location.substring(0, location.lastIndexOf("/"));
    const directoryName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: ¡muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Lo he conseguido con la tercera opción que me indicas. El único problema, era que al haber letras con acentos las cambiaba por caracteres especiales. Lo he resuelto con directoryName.replace(/%C3%A1/g, "á") varias veces (una para cada caracter especial) y funciona super bien. Genial tu respuesta!

Comment: Genial, recuerda dar upvote si la respuesta te sirvió, así los siguientes verán que es una respuesta "probada" (para el caso de la pregunta, claro).